# How to say "This song is dedicated to our parents " in Japanese?

Tags: translation

Here is what I got from Google Translate but from past experiences with Google translate I doubt it's accurate.

> この曲は、私たちの親に専用されています

Comment: "This song is for the personal use of my parents only."

Comment: You can never trust Google Translate as it can't tell the differences in usages and nuances.

Comment: Google translate's attempt is not considered a valid attempt so, as-is, your question is off-topic because we don't do translations. Nevertheless, the verb you are after is : 捧{ささ}げる

Comment: ^ Right... This might be of help: http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B2%E3%82%92%E6%8D%A7%E3%81%92%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99

Comment: It's better to use a verb 「捧げる」 here (e.g. 「この曲を私たちの両親に捧げる」).

Answer (score 2):

If it means for our parents,  I created this song,  it should be translated to:
この曲は私達の両親のために作りました。
If it's in a situation that before playing this song,  saying that "this song is dedicated to our parents."
It should be translated to:
私達の両親のために、この曲を演奏します。

Answer (score 1):

Roughly OK... but you should *not* translate "dedicated" to 専用. I would translate in the following manner:

> - この曲は私達の親のために作った。
>     <sup>* this song is made for our parents.</sup>
> - この曲は私達の親のために身を尽くして作った。
>     <sup>* this song is made to serve our parents.</sup>

See also: [Weblio (including Japanese)](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/dedicated)